# Red hat 6 (guest host from vmware) lost memory

Tags: linux, rhel, memory, vmware, ram

VMware Virtual Center 2.5.0
Resource allocated to GuestOS: RHEL 5 (64-bit)
**Memory: 4608 MB**
Memory overhead: 261 MB

```
[root@stend-mcstesb /]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

[root@stend-mcstesb /]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        4180644 kB
MemFree:          146068 kB
Buffers:          143936 kB
Cached:           211212 kB
SwapCached:        37924 kB
Active:          3038872 kB
Inactive:         876464 kB
Active(anon):    2857224 kB
Inactive(anon):   702968 kB
Active(file):     181648 kB
Inactive(file):   173496 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        1240480 kB
Dirty:              2444 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       3548036 kB
Mapped:            11084 kB
Shmem:                 4 kB
Slab:              55728 kB
SReclaimable:      32480 kB
SUnreclaim:        23248 kB
KernelStack:        2968 kB
PageTables:        11688 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4187468 kB
Committed_AS:    4440116 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       26468 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359706956 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   3411968 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       10240 kB
DirectMap2M:     4446208 kB

[root@stend-mcstesb /]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4082       3939        143          0        140        206
-/+ buffers/cache:       3592        490
Swap:         2047        836       1211
```

dmidecode -t 17 show 2 slot of 2048MB and 1 slot of 512MB
dmidecode -t 16 show **Maximum Capacity: 4 GB**
dmidecode -t 2 show Product Name: 440BX Desktop Reference Platform

Check other guestOS(rhel/windows) with 8GB RAM and also lost ~0.5GB(rhel) ~0.25GB(Windows). OK for Windows AGP 256MB but rhel?

**Where lost 4608-4082 = 526MB?**

Comment: 512mb AGP memory + 14mb kernel?

Comment: OK AGP 256MB for windows but rhel don't have X.

Answer (score 0):

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/454133

The kernel reserves some amount of memory (proportional to its total size) at the startup for a memory tables (for virtual-to-physical addresses translation). This memory given to the memory tables cannot be used by anything else and is subtracted from the total memory size reported.

The bigger physical RAM size is, the smaller is the ratio of the memory which cannot be used to the total physical RAM size:

```
On 12Gb desktop this ratio is around 4.5%
On 32Gb server this ratio is around 2%
On 512Gb server this ratio is around 1.56%
```

**Answer REDHAT: It is not a bug, it is a feature.**